# Add a word count feature that determines pay (for freelancer paid per word)

Tags: applications, applescript, pages, automation

I am a freelance writer and I frequently use Pages to draft my articles. I appreciate having the word count on the bottom of the document because I am often paid by the word. Periodically, I'll see how many words I've written, break out my calculator, and see how much money I've made for a bit of motivation.

However, I think it'd be really nice to have a little box next to word count that said how much money I've made so far. The function would get the current word count, I would pass it the constant of 'rate of pay per word,' and it would calculate how much I've made as I type.

I want to set the rate of pay per word in a drop-down or something and have the "money made" display next to the word count box.

I have some programming experience but I've never used Applescript or Automator. Can someone get me started with this? Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer so we can get the object to move down the page of it's own accord.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I originally had this using a Table. But have now changed it to a Text Object.

---

Here is you start then.

Save this Applescript as a **Stay Open** Application.

```
on idle
    tell application "Pages"
        set ActualCount to count words of body text of document 1

        set calculation to ActualCount * 0.02

        set object text of text item 1 of document 1 to (ActualCount & " words  = £" & calculation as string)

    end tell
    return 5 -- runs every n# seconds

end idle
```

---

[image]

---

Now in your document add a Text Object.

[image]

In the Text Object Arrange tab in the Format inspector.

Set the *Object Placement to **Move with text**.*

And *Text Wrap to **Above and Below**

This will save the need to manually move the Text Object down the document as you go.

[image]

---

Now run the App. Start typing.

The one thing you will notice is that the real word count sees the word in the table. **329** That is why I have included the word count in the text objects results.  **326 words  = £6.5**

---

[image]

---